# How can I include LeakCanary when using both build types and product flavors?

Tags: android, gradle, leakcanary

The [LeakCanary documentation](https://github.com/square/leakcanary#getting-started) mentions the following for handling build types:

```
 dependencies {
   debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.3.1'
   releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.3.1'
 }
```

However, what about when using multiple `product flavors` as well? I'm receiving an error `Gradle DSL method not found` on the `buildTypeCompile` functions.

Here is a skeleton of my current Gradle file:

```
android {
    ...

    dependencies {
        debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.3.1'
        ciCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.3.1'
        qaCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.3.1'
        uatCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.3.1'
        prodCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.3.1'
        releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.3.1'
    }

    productFlavors {
        foo {
            buildTypes {
                ci {
                    ...
                }

                qa {
                    ...
                }
            }
        }

        bar {
            buildTypes {
                ci {
                    ...
                }

                qa {
                    ...
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "on the buildTypeCompile functions" -- by "`buildTypeCompile` functions", do you mean `debugCompile` and `releaseCompile`?

Comment: FWIW, I took [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Service/DownloaderMNC), cloned the `support-v13` artifact into clones in `debugCompile` and `releaseCompile`, and I can successfully build all 8 build variants without a problem. You might wish to post more of your `build.gradle` file.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes, I do mean the `debugCompile` and `releaseCompile`, and in my case also `ciCompile` and a few others. I will post the skeleton of how I currently have it structured.

Comment: Why are your `buildTypes` closures inside product flavor closures? Build types are independent of product flavors. I have never seen them declared the way you have them; I always see them declared outside of `productFlavors`. Are all `...Compile` statements tied to build types?

Comment: @CommonsWare Yeah, I used to have the `buildTypes` up a level. The reason that I nested them under `productFlavors` is because certain variables, such as `API_URL`, need to be different across `buildTypes` and `productFlavors`. Currently the only error I see is for `ciCompile()`.

Comment: "Currently the only error I see is for `ciCompile()`" -- meaning if you comment that one out, other builds work? Or is it just that it happens to be the first non-standard build type, and then you get errors on `qaCompile` if you comment out `ciCompile`? Also, where in the `build.gradle` file are you actually creating those custom build types -- is it above or below where you have your `dependencies` declared?

Comment: @CommonsWare Bingo, my `dependencies` block had been moved above the `productFlavors` and `buildTypes`. I moved it below and now it works. Thank you! If you care to post this as an answer I will accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`build.gradle` is a script that builds up an object model of the build process. However, it is still a script, written in a scripting language (Groovy), and as such tends to be processed top-down.

Methods, like `debugCompile`, are generated when their corresponding object model objects are created. In the case of `debugCompile` and `releaseCompile`, since the `debug` and `release` build types are pre-defined, order does not matter too much. But for custom build types, and any product flavors, you need to define those first, before you try using generated methods.

The safest spot for module-level `build.gradle` file `dependencies` closures is at the end, after you're sure all your build types and product flavors exist, and therefore the corresponding `...Compile` methods exist.

Personally, I like having `dependencies` before `android`, and if you don't have custom build types or product flavors, that'll work.